# Move xy coordinates based on a given distance and bearing from transect

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a boat moving along a transect, looking for animals. Someone is stood on the top of the boat, facing forward, and is logging the distance from the boat and the bearing from the front of the boat when an animal is seen. I have this information as well as the xy coordinates of the boat at the point at which the animal was seen. **I need to get the xy coordinates of the animal itself based on this information.**

I don't have the original compass bearing of the boat, which makes this tricky; but what I do have is the next GPS (xy) coordinate of the boat, from which I can calculate a starting angle. From this, it should be possible to add or subtract the bearing at which the animal was seen to give a normalised angle which can be used to find the xy coordinates of the animal using trigonometry. Unfortunately my maths skills aren't quite up to the job.

I have several hundred points so I need to put this into a Python script to go through all the points.

In summary, the dataset has:

Original X, Original Y, End(next) X, End(next) Y, Bearing, Distance

EDIT: Sorry, I was in a rush and didn't explain this very well.

I see there being 3 stages to this problem.

1. Finding the original bearing of the transect
2. Finding the bearing of the point relative to the transect
3. Finding the new coordinates of the point based on this normalised angle and distance from the boat at the start xy

The Python code I had originally is below, although it's not much use - the figures given are examples.

```
    distFromBoat = 100
    bearing = 45


    lengthOpposite = origX-nextX
    lengthAdjacent = origY - nextY
    virtX = origX #virtual X
    virtY = origY-lengthOpposite #virtual Y
    angle = math.degrees(math.asin(math.radians((lengthOpposite/transectLen))))
    newangle = angle + bearing
    newLenAdj = math.cos(newangle)*distFromBoat
    newLenOpp = math.sqrt(math.pow(distFromBoat,2) + math.pow(newLenAdj,2) - 2*(distFromBoat*newLenAdj)*(math.cos(newangle)))
    newX = virtX-newLenOpp
    newY = origY-newLenAdj
    print str(newX) +"---"+str(newY)
```

**Thanks for any help in advance!**

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what exactly you're asking (the +/- part seems ambiguous). As a side note, I don't think you need to declare your ratio of `lengthOpposite`/`transectLen` as radians, that occurs on its own with the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, this is your problem:

- You have 2 points, `start` and `next` that you are walking between
- You want to find the coordinates of a third point, `New` that should be some distance and bearing from `start`, given that you are already facing from `start` to `next`.

My solution is this:

- Create a normalized vector from `start` to `next`
- Rotate your normalized vector by given bearing
- Multiply the normalized, rotated vector by your distance, and then add it to `start`
- treating `start` as a vector, the result of the addition is your new point

Because a counter-clockwise rotation ("left" from the current point) is considered positive, you need to invert `bearing` so that port is associated with negative, and starboard with positive.

**Code**

```
import math
origX = 95485
origY = 729380

nextX = 95241
nextY = 729215

distance = 2000.0
bearing = 45

origVec = origX, origY
nextVec = nextX, nextY


#Euclidean distance between vectors (L2 norm)
dist = math.sqrt((nextVec[0] - origVec[0])**2 + (nextVec[1] - origVec[1])**2)

#Get a normalized difference vector
diffVec = (nextVec[0] - origVec[0])/dist, (nextVec[1] - origVec[1])/dist


#rotate our vector by bearing to get a vector from orig towards new point
#also, multiply by distance to get new value
#invert bearing, because +45 in math is counter-clockwise (left), not starboard
angle = math.radians(-bearing)

newVec = origVec[0]+(diffVec[0]*math.cos(angle) - diffVec[1]*math.sin(angle))*distance, \
         origVec[1]+(diffVec[0]*math.sin(angle) + diffVec[1]*math.cos(angle))*distance

print newVec
```

**Output:**

> (93521.29597031244, 729759.2973553676)

Comment: When I tested this, it didn't seem to give the answer I was looking for, but as beroe's answer seemed to work I didn't look into why. Thanks though - you managed to explain my problem and solution much more elegantly than I did.

Comment: @JakeHanson: Thanks for the feedback. For myself, I'd like to know an example input/output that my program didn't work for so I can improve this answer.

Comment: If you look at the comment I put on beroe 's answer, there is an example set of values - unfortunately the answer beroe gave actually doesn't seem to be entirely correct either. I'd be grateful to hear what result you get from that example, the values your version give seem quite a way off to me - I'd expect the numbers to be in a similar region to the start and end xy values. Thanks again

Comment: I update the angle algorithm and it should work now...?

Comment: @JakeHanson: Whoops! It looks like I had done `nextVec[0] - origVec[1]` instead of `nextVec[0] - origVec[0]`! It should work splendidly now.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little problem with Matt's function, so I used `atan2` to get you the angle that the boat is going.

Edit: That was more complicated than I expected. In the end you need to subtract 90 and take the inverse to go from the geo-referenced angles to the trig angles.

(There is also an `angles` library (and probably other geography ones) that have this built in.

Now this takes the `origX` and `origY`, finds the trig angle and converts it to a `heading`, adds the bearing to the angle determined for the transect. Then it does trig on the distance, but using the angle converted back to trig degrees `-(X-90)`. It is kind of warped, because we are used to thinking of `0` degrees as north/up, but in trig it is "to the right", and trig goes counter clockwise vs clockwise for navigation.

```
import math

origX = 0.0
origY = 0.0

nextX = 0.0
nextY = -1.0

distance = 100.0
bearing = 45


def angle(origX,origY,nextX,nextY):
    opp = float(nextY - origY)
    adj = float(nextX - origX)
    return(math.degrees(math.atan2(adj,opp)))
# atan2 seems to even work correctly (return zero) when origin equals next

transectAngle = angle(origX,origY,nextX,nextY) # assuming the function has been defined
print "bearing plus trans", transectAngle + bearing
trigAngle = -(transectAngle + bearing -90)
print "trig equiv angle", trigAngle
newX = origX + distance * math.cos(math.radians(trigAngle))
newY = origY + distance * math.sin(math.radians(trigAngle))

print "position",newX,newY
```

Output:

```
-70.7106781187 -70.7106781187
```

Here is a function to print out a bunch of test cases (uses global vars so should be folded into the code above)

```
def testcase():
    bearinglist = [-45,45,135,-135]
    dist = 10
    for bearing in bearinglist:
        print "----transect assuming relative bearing of {}------".format(bearing)
        print "{:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}  {:>6}".format("x","y","tran","head","trigT","trigH","newX","newY")  
        for x in [0,.5,-.5]:
            for y in [0,.5,1,-.5]:
                # print "A:", x,y,angle(origX,origY,x,y)
                tA = newangle(origX,origY,x,y)
                trigA = -(tA-90)
                heading = tA + bearing
                trigHead = -(heading-90)
                Xnew = distance * math.cos(math.radians(trigHead))
                Ynew = distance * math.sin(math.radians(trigHead))
                print "{:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}  {:>6.1f}".format(x,y,tA,heading,trigA,trigHead,Xnew,Ynew)
```

[image] 
[image: adding paths]

Comment: Hmm actually, when origY > nextY, it doesn't seem to work properly. I'd be really grateful if you could check this, I can't actually work out a pattern as to how it's not working though...

Example values that don't seem to give the correct angle (by sight):

bearing = 45, dist = 2000, origxy = 95485,729380, nextxy = 95241,729215 gives me 95108, 731344 which doesn't look right at all

Comment: Something is wrong with the angle calculation function, so I made a new one using `atan2`. I also changed it to use a home-built `eq` function to test equality of floats, since you aren't supposed to use `==` due to precision issues.

Comment: With the new code, and your sample points, it gives `95864.3 727416.3` Does that look right?

Comment: I'm afraid not; that seems to be in the right place in the quadrant, but in the wrong quadrant - it should be around 93731, 730302. Not all the points are off by this amount though, some are in the right place.  Another error is one with a bearing of -10 and dist 2000 where X1 is roughly equal to X2 and Y2>Y1 (and should give a point almost to the north) gives a point at 2000m but at an angle which looks to be at about 100 degrees from north. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry for that. I am going to have to work on this later. Good case for unit testing. I made some tests but they happened to be right for the wrong reason! Not only are the trig functions 90° off, but they go the other way, so there is inverting to do once you get the angle (and before you get the final sin cos, and the angle from `atan2`....

Comment: Thanks for this; i'll check this on Monday and get back to you. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! This does work but i've decided to use Andy's script as it is a little cleaner... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It's (probably) possible there's a more elegant solution than this...assuming I understood your issue correctly. But, this will give you the bearing from your original location:

(inputs hard-coded as an example)

```
import math

origX = 0.0
origY = 0.0

nextX = 1.0
nextY = 0.0

Dist = ((nextX - origX)**2 + (nextY - origY)**2)**0.5

if origX == nextX and origY == nextY:
    angle = 0

if origX == nextX and nextY < origY:
    angle = 180

if nextY < origY and origX > nextX:
    angle = math.degrees(math.asin((nextX -origX)/Dist)) - 90

if nextX > origX and nextY < origY:
    angle = math.degrees(math.asin((nextX -origX)/Dist)) + 90

else:
    angle = math.degrees(math.asin((nextX -origX)/Dist))

print angle
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this solves problem 1+2 from my edited question - I just need to find the new coordinates of the point based upon this information now - any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This function turns out to be flawed. Turns out that [`atan2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) is an easy way to handle all the different quadrant conditions...